# Using @Validated causing CastException in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I am using Spring 3.1.

I am trying to use Bean-Validator to validate a method.

My class:

```
@Named
@Scope("prototype")
@Validated
public class MyClass implements someClass
{
..
    @Override
    public void handle(@NotNull MyObj myObj) {
        ..
    }
}
```

Now this is the calling class:

```
@Named
public class CallingClass{
..
  @Inject
  Provider<MyClass> myClass;

  public void doSomething(Myobj myObj)
  {
     MyClass handler = myClass.get();  //here I get the exception
     myClass.handle(myObj);
   }
```

That's the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85 cannot be cast to com...MyClass
```

Any idea?

thanks,
ray.

Comment: What about change this "@Inject
  Provider<MyClass> myClass;" as "@Inject
  Provider<SomeClass> myClass;"?

Comment: I tried the validation  in other classes and they being ignored. any idea why?

Comment: Did you add <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/> in your applicationContext?

Comment: Yes. I found something else. I tried NotEmpty for collection. it doesnt work but NotNull does work. Any idea?(I did clear() before to make sure it's really empty)

Comment: NotEmpty validates String only. I haven't tried method validation yet,  are you using hibernate-validator 4.2 or above? And is there any possibility the Validated annotaion is swallowed by the proxy mechanism? Are you using jdk proxy or cglib?

Comment: I am using 4.2 and i am using the jsr

Answer (score 0):

try to put @Validated and constraints on parameters to your interface if the object is not pojo.